# In SQL, when looking for specific strings of characters, which method is faster, substr or LIKE?

Tags: sql, case

I have got a case statement where I am trying replace values returned by the query with the new ones. I realized that there are different ways to accomplish this and I was wondering which would be the most efficient way of doing it, the two ways I was thinking of:

method 1

```
Case when myobject LIKE 'ABC%' then...else...end
```

method 2

```
case when substr(myobject,1,3) = 'ABC' then...else...end
```

Is any of these methods faster than the other? I am trying to make sure that my query is efficient as it could possibly be.

Comment: I'm 99% sure that in most typical cases, the first one will be the most effective one.

Comment: You can compare then in management Studio by using execution plan and executing both. it will show you the costs of both compared.

Comment: I think they will return same result, there is no % prior to ABC so the string has to begin with ABC, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Substr function will always return a value (and a row) (if you have enough characters) in the string but LIKE will do a search and may or may not return the row. As a result, the number of rows return may differ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `like` form is standard SQL.  As such, some databases will optimize this to use an index, when possible.

In particular, when looking for an initial sequence (as in your case), the SQL engine can choose to use an index on the column.  I don't think any database does a similar optimization for substrings.

So, the `like` form is preferred for two reasons.  It is standard SQL.  And, some databases can optimize it to take advantage of an index.

Comment: i think he wants to *select* the case to output a changed value, so indexes don't matter

Comment: Yes, it is a select statement and the database is based on Netezza so there are no indexes as far as I am aware. I will use LIKE statement as per the comments above, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The performance difference would be minimal to negligible.

Use `LIKE`, because readability beats a small/negligible performance gain every time.